# Should I have just minded my own business?

Tags: professionalism, work-environment, ethics, united-kingdom

I'm currently in the midst of a temporary position as an admin assistant/assistant to practice manager in a medium-sized city law firm.

I have written several posts about the nepotist/toxic environment this firm has although this could be indicative of most city law firms.

One of my responsibilities has been to order partners lunch every week by their assigned caterer, as the number of partners each week is variable depending on whether they're in court or on holiday or with clients etc. Three weeks into my post I noticed that one of the partners was an Orthodox/ practising  Jew as he wore a religious cap. I was slightly perplexed as to why we were ordering lunch   that included him as I thought that he would probably eat according to religious/ kosher guidelines.

So within two weeks of my employment I approached him in confidence and asked him if I could ask him a personal question. He replied yes. I asked him if he ate partners lunch every week. To which he replied he didn't because of his religious dietary requirements. I then said that I presumed as much and wanted to check with him as we were ordering 20 lunches from the caterer as opposed to 19 (which would've excluded him). I wanted him to confirm that he was happy for me to just order 19 lunches. He said it was not a problem. He said to me that it was 'very astute of me to have picked it up' and that it was 'well spotted'.As far as I was concerned the matter was concluded.

I then sent a message to all partners asking if they had any dietary requirements if they could let me know I could let the catering know as I could not see any record of it on the system. I believe that I was being efficient and using my initiative. I also believe that I was looking out for myself because if I was ordering the extra meal in error it would've been my neck on the line and knowing this firm I would probably be accused of doing it so I could enjoy a gourmet lunch each week myself!  I additionally think that I did very well that I asked the partner directly as opposed to asking the accounts dept or someone else in the admin office. So I believe that I handled the whole situation discreetly and professionally.

Fast forward to Friday where we had all gone out for drinks after work. It could've been the heat, it could've been that our tongues were loose with all the alcohol but one of my colleagues who is a senior solicitor and on very good terms with the partner said that one of the reasons why my contract would not be renewed it is because I made an issue of his religious belief/lifestyle and drew attention to the differences between him and the other partners and that I was borderline antisemitic. I cannot believe this! Not only is this an outright distortion of what I did I also believe it is discriminatory to me. If this partner is receiving flack from other partners it's probably because he did not inform the administrative office that he does not eat partners lunch for all these years... I think it's something like five years this arrangement had been going on so the costs are in the thousands.

I don't believe that I was in the wrong. However I'm aware that there is a difference between what is right and wrong in a professional environment and wonder do you think I should've just minded my own business given that I am just on a six month temporary contract? Do you also think that I have any grounds for a complaint against what was said to me. I understand that it was said off work premises and it was also said well we were slightly intoxicated but I think that there is a lack of boundaries and someone speaking so freely to me. I really don't appreciate being labelled anti-semitic or being made a scapegoat for simply doing my job

Edit -forgot to mention that he told me he at fruit at the partners lunch is that he would bring himself. I asked him if I could order a fruit platter or something and he said no probably because he didn't want to risk contamination. So it was obvious to all partners that he did not eat the same lunch as them. My only reason for approaching him is the cost of the lunch that was going to waste/someone else eating and that I may be held liable for it in someway.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137846/discussion-on-question-by-user311438-should-i-have-just-minded-my-own-business).

Answer (score 4):

When you noticed the guy with the religious cap, you could have done one of the following:

- Send the message about dietary requirements without singling out the individual.  You would have avoided the fallout about discriminating against anyone.
- Pretend like you didn't see it at all.  Unfortunately, with the environment you're in, this could have also backfired because they'd want to blame you for not noticing.

Either way, this whole situation seems toxic.  The better questions to ask are why the last person in your role isn't there any more, and where you're going to end up next.

Comment: +1 for this. A general inquiry about satisfaction with the meals or any dietary requirements would have been proactive and helpful. Among other issues many people pick and choose the degree of strictness with which they observe their religious traditions. That is none of the OP's business. By singling out the one partner the OP was making themselves intrusive.

Comment: I recently retired from a UK legal organisation. I am a Gentile. I was once on the phone to a Jewish judge who I got on well with. I told him the joke about the Jewish gay guy who called his (traditional) mother to say he had turned straight and was marrying someone who, it transpires, is Monica Lewinsky (punch line: what happened to that nice black boy you were seeing last year?). Some colleagues were staring at me open mouthed (they didn't hear him laugh a lot). When the judge visited our office, he called out, 'Hey, Mike! I told that joke at our rabbi's dinner party and got a great laugh!'.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing that you did seems wrong. You were being earnest and attentive to the needs of everyone and obviously tried to do the right thing even though your knowledge of the situation and the people involved was limited.

Unfortunately in such rigidly hierarchical organizations where there's extreme "power distance" between (in this case) partners and temp help, there's no easy way to correct a misunderstanding. Just be glad that you're not going to be working for such people much longer.

Answer (score 2):

- Assume that partners in law firms are able to speak up for themself if their dietary requirements are not met.

Think about in which role you did this.

- Were you checking if the caterer was delivering "too much", and if so why? (Maybe your business)
- Were you checking trying to cut costs? (Maybe your business)
- Were you checking if people were inattentive with the companies money? (none of your business i guess)
- Were you trying to make take care of employees dietary wishes (None of you business)

If you want to address such a question, keep it tentative and informal (e.g. "is everybody happy with the choices of the caterer?"). Do not speculate what may or may not be included in the way in which other people live their religion.

Comment: I don't agree with your assessment on the final bullet. Anyone responsible for ordering meals should aware of these things. The line was crossed when she pressed even though the partner had indicated it was already resolved satisfactorily.

Comment: @JoelEtherton It's not that the OP should ignore dietary issues.  But rather than guessing as to what those issues are, the OP should just be open to any requests, or should send a general "does anyone have any special requests" message.  If no one says anything, assume that people are ok with it.  It's not like the partners don't see leftover food.

Comment: @DaveG: The matter had already been settled. The general message serves no purpose except to call out the difference of one individual. If there are remaining questions to be settled, they should be settled privately.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: Partner X is a single father or mother and takes the Jewish colleagues dinner home with him as a nice well-cooked meal for his child. You wouldn’t want the tax man to know, but all the other partners happily agree to keep it quiet. And there you come stepping on everyone’s toes…

Or consider this: Jewish partner secretly loves non-kosher food. All the partners know it. But he can’t admit this to anyone on your low level, and as a result, he got no meal. Congratulations.

Or consider this: Partner Z doesn’t weigh 350 pound for no reason. Since he does an excellent job, nobody minds him having two dinners.

In the position that you were in and that you will remain in for the shortest legally possible time, you have to be very careful whose toes you are stepping on. Common sense is that if there was a leftover meal every week, someone would have said something.

Comment: My goodness, what an absurdly active imagination you have.

Comment: All very reasonable assumptions. Yours was unreasonable: Every week there is one meal untouched, and nobody has said a word. And in the end, you DID step on someone's toes. And official reasons are very often not the real reasons.

Comment: Reason why nobody said a word is because they had an incompetent admin team  . One of whom was helping themselves to the free meal. It's important to remember that whilst I may ask for an opinion on a situation you are not privy to all the facts of it. Nothing that you have said is reasonable. Just unfounded speculation.

Answer (score -1):

> do you think I should've just minded my own business given that I am
> just on a six month temporary contract?

Yes.

> Do you also think that I have any grounds for a complaint against what
> was said to me.

Absolutely not.

> I understand that it was said off work premises and it was also said
> well we were slightly intoxicated but I think that there is a lack of
> boundaries and someone speaking so freely to me. I really don't
> appreciate being labelled anti-semitic or being made a scapegoat for
> simply doing my job

You should probably avoid going out for drinks after work if you don't like what is being said. You must certainly know that people (particularly slightly intoxicated people) tend to speak freely at such events.

You are hurt by the fact that they aren't renewing your contract. You seem to be looking for reasons to dislike the company and the employees. Just do your job, mind your own business, and find a better place to work.

Comment: +1 for "avoid going out for drinks after work". These people are not your buddies and alcohol and money don't mix.